My plugin for Elementor works locally but not on prod
I'm currently working on a plugin for Elementor. This plugin adds a widget that is able to import 3D files like .glb or .gltf, and then display them with the lib ThreeJS
I started web dev 1 year ago so still a rookie, moreover, I work alone for this project so it might be cursed. I'm doing an internship and it's my mission to develop this plugin, I worked on this for almost 2 months and I resolved a lot of problems by myself, but this one is hardcore.
The problem I met with the plugin is when I uploaded it to an online WordPress installation. For the last 2 months I used a local WordPress to develop my plugin, and when I finished it (like 1 week ago), a coworker wanted to try it to see what I've done, but it didn't work as I expected.
Here you can see how it looks on my local WordPress:

As you can see, there is an Elementor GIF (I added it manually, it's the background image of my div) and in the left the parameters to customize the widget.
And when you want to preview the page:

The 3D file appears, you can customize everything like the background color, speed rotation, interactivity etc...
BTW my folder architecture look like this:

So it works on my local WP, but in the prod WP when I click on the button to preview the page, my plugin is not here, as you can see on those screenshots:
Console on draft page:

Console on preview page:

I don't know why, on my local WP there is no problem but on my prod WP my plugin won't appear on the preview page (and also the post page). Another example of my problem, when I'm on the draft page, there is a console.log('SCRIPT JS CHARGE'); showing that the plugin works, but not on the preview page.
Of course I tried to deactivate the other plugins, nothing changed, I also tried to remove/add my plugin again, nothing.
Today I tried to create a new plugin, a very basic one with just one utility: add text on the page, that's all, I also added a script js doing a console.log("test"); just to be sure.
Same as my main plugin, I had my console.log in the console but when I switched on the preview page my plugin was not there.
I also tried to create a new version of my plugin but still the same plugin so no results.
My plugin works on local, I thought it was done, but what's the utility if my plugin only work on my local WP. My mission for my internship was only to create this plugin and my internship end today, so I will consider this as a fail. I tried to work with ChatGPT, StackOverflow, Reddit etc.. I tried to change a lot of code inside my plugin, but still useless on prod WordPress.

Good to hear your initiative to create an add-on for Elementor.
It's hard to pinpoint the exact issue with the information you have provided, so the best I can do is layout some recommendations:

Check compatibilities, ensure that your dev environment aligns closely with prod environment. Verify that Wordpress, Elementor and PHP versions are consistent across both environments.

Directory structure, I noticed a discrepency with your folder structure and the recommended folder structure on Elementor's documentation. The root level of your addon directory /SOW_3D/ should contain an SOW_3D.php file. Best practice is to give the folder and main file the same name. Here is how I would suggest you restructure your folder:



    sow-3d/
    |-- assets/
    |   |-- images/
    |      |-- elementor.gif
    |   |-- js/
    |      |-- gtlf-loader.js
    |      |-- orbit-controls.js
    |      |-- three.js
    |   |-- includes/
    |      |-- widgets/
    |          |-- script.js
    |          |-- sow3d-widget.php
    |-sow-3d.php

Note: It's best to follow a single naming convention, I personally prefer it like this but you can change it to however you like.

Plugin header, ensure that your plugin file includes a standard plugin header to ensure Wordpress recognises your plugin, it should look something like this:



Loading process, ensure that you are loading Elementor's functionality by wrapping the code into a separate function. This code loads when the WordPress plugins_loaded action hook is fired.

The following code can be used to run the functionality:

    function sow-3d() {
    
        // your code here
    
    }
    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'sow-3d' );


Debugging, always keep WP_DEBUG enabled in your dev environment in order to catch errors early.

I hope this helps, good luck!
